# How can I create an object of type doctor inside the Node class?

Tags: c++

I am a bit of a beginner with C++ so I apologize if it's a silly question. I am trying to create an object of type Doctor inside the struct Node, but the compiler displays that Doctor isn't a valid type. I figured this is because Node is declared before Doctor, so is there a way to make Node familiar with Doctor?

```
struct Node
{
 public:
 Doctor d;
 Node *next;
};

class Doctor
{
 private: 
 int appCount = 0; //number of appointments today
 int doctorCode = 0;

 public:
 Node *head, *tail;

 Doctor() 
 {
  head = NULL;
  tail = NULL;
  }

  int getAppCount() { return appCount; }
  int getDoctorCode() { return doctorCode; }


  void setAppCount(int count) { appCount = count; }
  void setDoctorCode(int code) { doctorCode = code }

  };
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `d.getDoctorCode() = 0;`? This line does not make any sense in a class declaration

Comment: No. First of you are calling the getter, not the setter. Second of that's not how you call a function. Third you are not allowed to call functions directly in a class declaration (you'd probably want to do that in a constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Its simple that u cant link both objects before initializing it either u have to initialize the Node Structure or the Doctor Class then only you have to link in the Structures or Classes.
"link" i here mean to say that the Calling of Node in Doctor Class where Node Structure Depends on the instantiation of Doctor Class. Try compiling removing the Dependencies.